# Benefits to Using a Memory Stream over Reading From File

Tags: c#, .net, email, memorystream

I was recently looking at a piece of code that was attaching a file to an email using [System.Net.Mail.Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx).  The current implementation was storing the attachment as a file to a storage device and giving it a unique name.  This file then was appended to the [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage) as follows:

```
Attachment data = new Attachment(filename);
message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Email was then sent and the file was then deleted from the storage device.

Wouldn't it be faster/better for the file to just be stored in a MemoryStream (which it already is) and then just pass that as the attachment to the Email?  I would imagine somewhere in the MailMessage class the file is being read into a stream and sent in the very same manner, and the whole process of storing it to disk is completely unnecessary.

My gut... Writing to disk is completely unnessarry and using the stream should be implemented. (am i wrong?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would be better to avoid writing it to disk, unless that step is necessary for some other reason.  The `Attachment` class can take a stream and a file name as arguments to its constructor, rather than giving it a physical file path.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws.aspx

Comment: I understand there is a stream version, just seeing if the implementer  was thinking about something I am overlooking. Or they just didn't understand streams but working with raw files was more familiar so they went that path.

Comment: @cgatian Most likely the latter.  The only reason I can think of to write it to a file first would be for archiving/backup/fail-safety.

Answer (score 0):

Sure; `Attachment` even has a constructor that takes a stream and a name, so writing the file to disk can be removed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

While this is definitely possible, consider two things before you make the change: 1. The time the attachment lives as a MemoryStream. 2. If it would be considerably longer without writing the file, then also your system mail throughput and resulting memory pressure.

Comment: It looks like it's read and deleted all within the same method. However very good point.